# Nesting BlocBuilder inside BlocListener causes exception on hot reload

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm currently using a BlocConsumer to hand loading of data form an API, and also handling user actions such as tapping.

Data is loaded from an API and when successful rebuilds the widget with the new data. The listener is present to detect when the user taps on an item and the state change results in a navigation change.

Although this works, if I perform a hot reload an exception occurs. This makes me assume there is a better way to do what I'm trying to do.

So far, I have:

```
 MultiBlocProvider(
  providers: [
    BlocProvider<MyBloc>(
      create: (context) => MyBloc(MyRepositoryImpl()),
    ),
  ],
  child: BlocConsumer<MyBloc, MyState>(
    listenWhen: (previous, current) => current is ItemTappedState,
    listener: (context, state) {
      if (state is ItemTappedState){
        
      }
    },
    buildWhen: (previous, current) {
      return current is MyStateSuccess;
    },
    builder: (context, state) {
      List<dynamic> data = [];   
  
      if (state is MyStateInitial){
        context.read<MyBloc>().add(const MyAction());
        return const Padding(padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.all(20), child:Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
      } else if (state is MyStateSuccess){
        data = (context.read<MyBloc>().state as MyStateSuccess).data;
        <!-- EXCEPTION HERE -->
      }

      return Container(...);
    }
  )
)
```

Exception: `type 'ItemTappedState' is not a subtype of type 'MyStateSuccess' in type cast.`

This is caused when I tap on an item, prompting the `ItemTappedState` to be the last state and then reload.
`(context.read<MyBloc>().state as MyStateSuccess)` fails presumably because the `if block` was previously satisfied but the state type has changed.

It isn't a HUGE issue as the code still functions correctly, however, it feels as though I should be doing something different so that it functions correctly under all circumstances!

Comment: You have a bloc consumer for `LeaguesBloc`, but then you're reading from a different bloc called `MyBloc` and casting it to the same state type as `LeaguesBloc`, is that right?

Comment: Oops! No, I edited to generic names and forgot one! My bad!

Comment: Inside your builder, you read the state of the Bloc using `data = (context.read<MyBloc>().state as MyStateSuccess).data` even though you have access to the `state` reference given to your by the builder method, can you simply do `data = (state as MyStateSuccess).data` and see if that solves your problem?

Comment: It did indeed! It didn't like the cast! Nice one! (New to bloc fyi!)